# Vectorize Spark built-in functions

Tags: python, apache-spark, pyspark, apache-spark-sql

**Context:**

I have a data-frame with a Sparse vector of size 1000 and I need to apply the natural logarithm to it.
I want to take advantage of the bult-in function that already provide spark, but it doesn't work on vectors. Here is the documentation:

```
from pyspark.sql.functions import log1p

Signature: log1p(col)
Docstring:
Computes the natural logarithm of the given value plus one.

.. versionadded:: 1.4
File:      /usr/spark-2.4.4/python/pyspark/sql/functions.py
Type:      function
```

Is there any function in Spark that could do something like this?

```
from pyspark.sql.functions import log1p, col, udf
import numpy as np
import math

log = np.vectorize(math.log1p)

df.withColumn('log_features', log(col('features'))
```

I'm currently using an udf, but is not really efficient.

```
@udf(returnType=VectorUDT())
def UDF_calculate_Log_Features(vector):
    vector.values = [math.log1p(x) for x in vector.values]
    return vector

df.withColumn('features_log', UDF_calculate_log_features(col('features'))
```

Here is the data-frame:

```
df.select('features').show(5, 72) # 176M rows aprox.

## +------------------------------------------------------------------------+
## |                                                                features|
## +------------------------------------------------------------------------+
## |                                  (10000,[1677,2549,3891],[1.0,1.0,1.0])|
## |                                   (10000,[714,2212,2812],[1.0,1.0,1.0])|
## |                                  (10000,[2146,2815,7826],[1.0,1.0,1.0])|
## |(10000,[2049,5377,6014,7239,8395,8848,9318,9367],[1.0,1.0,1.0,1.0,1.0...|
## |       (10000,[4694,6597,7595,8545,8869,9187],[2.0,1.0,1.0,1.0,1.0,1.0])|
## +------------------------------------------------------------------------+
```